# mailto: links unsupported in Android?

Tags: android, mailto

I dont have a real Android device so I'm using emulators for all my development for now, are mailto: web links really unsupported on Android devices 2.1 and below? 2.2 works, but every time I click a `mailto:` link on 1.6 or 2.1 even, I get an [unsupported action] dialog. Anybody with a real device want to test this out?

Comment: Mailto links where? In a WebView?

Comment: in the mobile browser using 10.0.2.2 to get to localhost.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to handle it yourself in a WebViewClient

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    Activity mContext;
    public MyWebViewClient(Activity context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {     
        if(url.startsWith("mailto:")){
            MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mt.getTo()});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mt.getSubject());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, mt.getCc());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mt.getBody());
            mContext.startActivity(i);
            view.reload();
            return true;
        }
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your activity you keep a reference to `MyWebViewClient` and assign it to your `webview` with `setWebViewClient(mWebClient)`.

Comment: A minor caveat regarding this solution: the method always returns true, which tells the WebView that "our implementation of WebViewClient handles everything" - this can create problems for edge cases of redirections, such as using `location.replace()` in JavaScript. Instead of `view.loadUrl(url); return true;` you can type `return false;` to achieve the same effect without introducting bugs. See my longer explanation in [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14335335/241456)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way would be:

```
if(url.startsWith("mailto:")){
    Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: `if (MailTo.isMailTo(url)) { //...`

Comment: I believe Intent.parseUri throws a URISyntaxException so you need to handle with a try { ... } catch { ... }