# Redirect to a mobile app from a web page

Tags: android

How to open an android application when a particular link in mobile browser,is clicked?

Comment: Do i need to modify the web page ?? If so, plz tel how??

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017013/open-dialog-to-choose-browser/15017233#15017233

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Comment: @tozka i hv tried that ...din work for me...nyways thanks for responding

Comment: @Kirit ...din't help...plz read the question again...

Answer (score 1):

To open your application when a link is clicked, you have to:

- define a specific protocol `protocol://` and use it in the URI of the href in your web page
- make sure your app catches the click by adding a few lines in its manifest.

This should help: [How to listen for a custom URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471503/how-to-listen-for-a-custom-uri)