# How to redirect to an Activity from a link of a webview?

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I need to know if there is a posibility of run an intent after click a hyperlink inside a webview.

The flow will be the next:

1. Activity with a WebView
2. A oauth registration web is loaded inside the webview
3. When you have registered the web redirect you to another web which says "Ok, you are registered now"

I want to know if there is something to load another activity when the webview charges this second web saying "Ok, you are registered now".

I read the next post [handling links in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788461/handling-links-in-a-webview), but I think that this is not the same problem, because it is done in the first web that is loaded in the webview.

Answer (score 2):

But you can catch:

```
if(url.startsWith("your second url")){
```