# Android web view new links

Tags: android, webview

I have a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) inside a fragment and for example when a user opens that part of my application with the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) I will show him a website for example ebay or amazon. My problem is that when he clicks on another link from that [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) the new link will open in the default browser. 
Is there a way to continue opening the links in my [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)?

Comment: Bear in mind security issues when opening an external website inside a WebView in your app (refer http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#WebView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebViewClient` for that

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(url.contains("amazon"))  //compare urls that should open in same webview
        {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
        else
        {    
            //open in default browser
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to set your webclient to the webview explicitly like this

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Setting a WebViewClient to the WebView works. 
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a custom `WebViewClient` to your `WebView` to handle this.

The question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788461/handling-links-in-a-webview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738328/shouldoverrideurlloading-in-webview-for-android-not-running).