# Err_Unknown_URL_Scheme Android Kotlin

Tags: android, html, webview

I am new to Android and Kotlin. When I create my own HTML page. I include some links like

`<a href='tel:8787878787'>Call our customer service</a>`

Finally found ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME error. 
I found the answer here in Java.

[Android WebView err_unknown_url_scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693263/android-webview-err-unknown-url-scheme)

But I want in Kotlin.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
webViewFeed.webViewClient=object : WebViewClient(){
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
        if (URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url)) {
            return false
        }
       else {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).