# Open non-http links in browser in java

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-intent, uri

I have an url in my app like "zoommtg://us04.zoom.com". I want to open it in browser by Intent. As it is not http or https, it can't be parsed by `Uri.parse(url)`. Again if I try `url="http://"+url;` it works but deletes the ":" from "zoommtg://" resulting wrong url! I am using the solution of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693263/android-webview-err-unknown-url-scheme)

Comment: That is not an URL that any browser will be able to handle. If you put this into a browser *manually*, does it work? It looks like Zoom app could handle that.

Comment: @GenerousBadger Clicking on the link doesn't open zoom app directly. Instead, the link should be opened in browser and then browser will start zoom.

Answer (score 0):

if it is working for `https` but not other requests, then you can try setting `cleartexttraffic` to true in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Do tell if that fixes it. :)

Comment: src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:14: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cleartexttraffic' in package 'android'

Answer (score 0):

`zoommtg` seems to be "custom protocol" declaration, which isn't resolveable by web browser, but if you are shure, that `http(s)` url version will work then just replace scheme

```
String url = "zoommtg://us04.zoom.com";
url = url.replaceFirst("zoommtg", "https")
```

if you really need to use unsecure `http` then you have to allow app to do such requests, see [how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

btw. you still can use `Uri` class, it isn't limited to web protocols... check out some [description of this structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

> URI = scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]

you can parse your `String` to `Uri` and just replace `scheme` part

```
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();
url = builder.scheme("https").build().toString();
```