# Open bank application is failing with Flutter WebView and StripeCheckout

Tags: android, flutter, webview, stripe-payments, payment

I use Stripe Checkout in a `WebView` in Flutter.

During the payment flow using Ideal (Netherlands based banking system) the flow tries to open an external app and sends a URL like the following:

```
nl.abnamro.ideal://%7B%22idealTransaction%22...
```

this is the WebView relevant code:

```
WebView(
   initialUrl: initialUrl,
   javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
   onWebViewCreated: (controller) => _controller = controller,
   navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) async {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://example.com/succes')) {
            ...
            Navigator.pop(context, status); // <-- Handle success case
          } else if (request.url.startsWith('https://example.com/cancel')) {
            Navigator.pop(context, Status.paymentCanceled); // <-- Handle cancel case
          }
          if (request.url.startsWith("https") || request.url.startsWith("http")) {
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          }
          _launchURL(request.url);
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        })
```

the `_launcURL` method is

```
_launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }}
```

and what I get in output is

```
Could not launch nl.abnamro.ideal://%7B%22idealTransaction%22%3A%7B%22i...
```

and my flow gets stuck.

This deep link should open the ABN Amro app, which is installed on my device.
This actually works on iOS.

Do you know what is the best way to deal with this flow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693263/android-webview-err-unknown-url-scheme/53059413#53059413

Comment: But overall you should not use Checkout in a WebView, you should either do payments in the system browser entirely outside of your app, or use the Stripe Flutter plugin.

Comment: how will I get back the outcome of the payment if I do everything on the browser? Do you have any example/link?

Comment: Your backend gets a webhook and you could notify your app from the backend. Or set the `success_url` on the CheckoutSession to a URL that redirects to a URL scheme your app opens. Or you could integrate using the Stripe Flutter SDK which I believe works with callbacks when the payment is complete

Comment: Have this same issue but with MangoPay, instead of Stripe Checkout.

Comment: @alexlipa So what was the solution for this in the end?