# Android how is a Chrome intent-based URI opened

Tags: android, uri, deep-linking

From the [Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/), I understand apps can be opened with the following URI

```
intent:  
   HOST/URI-path // Optional host  
   #Intent;  
      package=\[string\];  
      action=\[string\];  
      category=\[string\];  
      component=\[string\];  
      scheme=\[string\];  
   end;
```

I was wondering if I could open this URI from my app.

Example URI

```
intent:
    //qr/json/%7B%22u%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fprivacybydesign.foundation%2Fbackend%2Firma%2Fsession%2FvsRjkZF2B2H17sBWmVZe%22%2C%22irmaqr%22%3A%22disclosing%22%7D
    #Intent;
        package=org.irmacard.cardemu;
        scheme=cardemu;
        l.timestamp=1620907855707;
        S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dorg.irmacard.cardemu
    ;end
```

Since it look like a normal URI I thought I could open it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("%EXAMPLE_URI%"));
startActivity(intent);
```

That gives me an `ActivityNotFoundException`. What am I missing?

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=intent://qr/json/{"u":"https://privacybydesign.foundation/backend/irma/session/vsRjkZF2B2H17sBWmVZe","irmaqr":"disclosing"} pkg=org.irmacard.cardemu (has extras) }

Comment: From where you are calling the startActivity(intent); ?

Comment: From my mainactivity

Comment: The intent will be used by chrome to identify your app and launch the app if it's installed. internally you can't use it to launch activity.

Comment: If chrome can do it, i should be able to do the same right?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe there are different ways to handle it based on the outcome you are expecting exactly. Can you give me more context about how and why you are using it?

Answer (score 1):

The "intent:" syntax described in the [Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/) is used to **launch apps from a web page**, Chrome will handle the `href` and retrieve the params to launch apps via the Android Intent.

The scheme of the example URI you provided is `intent://`, it is not handled by default.

if you want to handle the `intent://` URI, you need to [create a deep link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

If you want to open a web page from your Android app, you can use the ACTION_VIEW action and specify the web URL in the intent data.

```
public void openWebPage(String url) {
    Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

// example
// openWebPage("https://privacybydesign.foundation/backend/irma/session/vsRjkZF2B2H17sBWmVZe")
```

more info about [Intents and Intent Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)

Comment: But how does chrome handle it?

Comment: Chrome uses WebView to load web pages, and catch the `href` links by WebViewClient. An example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788461/handling-links-in-a-webview

Answer (score 0):

Here are several things you could try:

**1. Make sure the application that you want to start has implemented the right intent.**

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
...
    <activity android:name=".PleaseStartThisActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
</application>
```

**2. Always use a new intent and never reuse the old one.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); //OK.
// Intent intent = getIntent(); //Not OK.
```

**3. Set everything else right.**

```
// If package name and activity are known.
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.irmacard.cardemu", "org.irmacard.cardemu.PleaseStartThisActivity"));
// Else
// intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + filePath), "text/plain");
```

**4. Set or add flags might help**

```
intent.setFlags(
    android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT |
    android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP |
    android.content.Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES |
    android.content.Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND |
    android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION |
    android.content.Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION |
    android.content.Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION |
    android.content.Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
    android.content.Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

**5. Now you can safely start the activity.**

```
startActivity(intent);
// Or this:
// startActivity(android.content.Intent.createChooser(intent, null));
```

**EDIT**

```
* intent.getDataString() - To get intent data (You may have to parse it to get the package name).
* getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities() - To check available activities for that package like the following example:
```

```
private final String getActivity(final String packageName, final Intent intent, final Bundle bundle, final String mimeType) {
        final String activity;
        int activityLen = 0;
        final int packageLen = packageName.length();
        
        if(bundle != null && (activity = bundle.getString("activity")) != null) {
            activityLen = activity.length();
        } else {
            activity = null;
        }

        final List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
        
        for(ResolveInfo ri : list) {        
            final IntentFilter filter = ri.filter;  

            final String activityName = ri.activityInfo.name;
            //Make sure the activity is valid and exist for the package.
            //Tolerate with case insensitive
            if(activity != null && activity.regionMatches(true, 0, activityName, 0, activityLen)
               && packageName.regionMatches(true, 0, ri.activityInfo.packageName, 0, packageLen)) {
                return activityName;
            } else if(filter == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: No available ACTIONS to handle this file", 1).show();
                return null;
                //Auto search only if user hasn't specified the activity, else return null. Tolerate with case insensitive
            } else if(activity == null && filter.hasAction(intent.getAction()) && filter.hasDataType(mimeType)) {
                if(ri.activityInfo.packageName.regionMatches(true, 0, packageName, 0, packageLen)) {
                    return ri.activityInfo.name;
                }
            } // Else keep validating next activities
        }
        
        if(activity == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: No available ACTIVITIES to open this file", 1).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: No such activity found", 1).show();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure Chrome has not declared every possible activity out there.

Comment: It's not about Chrome but the app itself. Does the app has `android.intent.action.VIEW` as activity in its `Manifest.xml`? Make sure to pass the right mime type as well. I've noticed if the mime: `*/*`, android package installer might be called.