# mailto URI parse in android

Tags: android

I have a button that sends feedback. In the emulator it currently says "Unable to perform this operation". Will my app say this in the real device too ? If so what is the workaround to implementing mailto function ? i did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671303/mailto-links-unsupported-in-android) page but I can not implement a webView in my MainActivity

```
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.feedback);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri address = Uri.parse("mailto:prasana91@gmail.com?subject=calculator_feedback");
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,address);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the code from the link you posted. I haven't tried it, but I don't see why it wouldn't work:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "prasana91@gmail.com" });
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "calculator_feedback");
startActivity(i);
```

Let me know if that worked.

Comment: an Activity extends Context, which is why it can actually just call startActivity(x)

Comment: Hey the activity for email does get invoked but it does not auto fill the mail id and subject line like I want it to. How to do this. the putExtras seem to be ignored

Comment: @prasanavenkat Sorry, I don't know why it would do that. Maybe it's the wrong app? For example, it should be opening the default mail app, but it's opening the gmail app?