# history.back() does not refresh page on android brower

Tags: javascript, android, browser-history, html5-history

I have 2 pages A and B. I have a link to redirect A to B and there is a history.back() in B back to A. I put a alert at the beginning of A. When I test it on desktop browser the alert works, but when I test it on android browser the alert does not work.

Actually I found there is one of my page work on android browser, when I looked into detail I believe the following code make it work.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError,{
//                    timeout: 10000,
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                });
            }
```

the only thing I can think of is that there is a callback(locationSuccess) in the above code. But why?

I want to have history.back() work with refresh on android browser. Some one mentions some other methods like location.href = document.referrer;history.go(-1). But I don't want one record being stored in history.

anyone have any idea? thanks.

Comment: refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333620/android-webview-location-replace-doesnt-work?rq=1), might be helpful to you

Comment: my code have nothing to do with android webview. it's just android browser